# PYQT: TableWidget: Replacing the "nan" Cells

Tags: python-3.x, pyqt, pyqt5

I have a Table Widget which is populated from an excel data. Because some of the excel cells are empty, some cells in the Table Widget have the entry **nan**. For aesthetic reasons I want to replace them in the Table Widget with **-**.
It seems that my code for that is doing nothing, so I could use some advice here.

```
    for i in range(len(df.index)):
        for j in range(len(df.columns)):
            if self.ui.RefWidget.item(i, j) == QtWidgets.QTableWidgetItem("nan"):
                self.ui.RefWidget.setItem(i, j, QtWidgets.QTableWidgetItem("-"))
            else:
                pass
```

**RefWidget** is the Table Widget.

**df** is the excel dataframe.

Solved it:

```
    for i in range(len(df.index)):
        for j in range(len(df.columns)):
            if self.ui.RefWidget.item(i, j).text() in ["nan"]:
                self.ui.RefWidget.item(i,j).setText("-")
            else:
                pass
```